# Git Revert deleted another developer's work. Why?

Tags: git, git-flow

In my company, our git workflow goes like this, we create a `feature branch` from `master`, develop on that `feature branch` until we're finished. Then we create a PR to merge to `master` and then merge that `feature branch` to `test`. Merging to `test` deploys the application to a test server. Once testing is finish and we get the green light, a developer reviews the PR and merges it to `master` which in turn deploys the application to a staging environment.

I was working on a feature branch and accidentally merged `test` into the `feature branch` (instead of merging `master` into the `feature branch`) so when I created the PR, it had all the changes I made but also the changes of the other developers who merged to `test` but were not in `master`. I reverted the merge: `git revert -m 1 <commit before merge hash>` and then merged that branch into `test`. Afterwards I get a message from a really angry developer saying that I deleted their work (their work was in `test`). I want to understand why this happened, I wanted to revert to a commit before the merge ONLY IN MY BRANCH, create the PR, and then merge to `test`, hopefully merging my branch with that developer's changes in `test`. It seemed to have deleted their work though. Can anyone explain to me why this has happened?

Comment: Reverting a merge means *back out everything the merge brought in*. And that means *everything*.

Comment: @torek how would I back out everything the merge brought only in my branch without deleting that work when merging to another branch?

Comment: That's where things get really sticky, because `git revert` adds a *new commit* that says: *all that stuff? that's bad, let's get rid of it.* So your branch now declares that it shall be gone. To un-declare that, you can revert the revert, making a new commit: *all that stuff? it's good again, bring it back.*

Comment: Your other option is to rewrite your branch history, removing the initial revert. Now your branch says nothing at all about the merge. The hard part here is that if anyone else *depends* on your commits that make up the old history, they still need the old history, not the new rewritten history in which you never did a revert at all.

Comment: ok thanks @torek for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the git help:

> **git-revert - Revert some existing commits**
>
> *-m parent-number, --mainline parent-number*
>
> Usually you cannot revert a merge because you do not know which side of the merge should be considered the mainline. This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the change relative to the specified parent.
>
> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.

As we can see in the docs reverting merge commits may not be straight-forward.

For this reason it is really hard to tell you *why* this happened without knowing your history tree.

But when this kind of situation happens, I usually do not use `git-revert` for merge commits.

Instead I use the following simple approach that may also work for you:

First communicate to your team members what happened and that you are going to fix it and they should synchronize once you are done.

Go to your `feature` branch and reset it to the commit prior to the bad merge:

```
$ git reset --hard hash_of_commit_prior_to_bad_merge
$ git push -f
```

Your branch is cleaned up. Now go to the `test` branch and do the same, first reset prior to your merge and force push to update the remote.

At this point both branches are clean.

Now you can start again by updating your branch and following your process normally.

Let people know it is fixed.

This approach is clean and works fine as long as you do it right after the occurrence and your team allows you to force push.

As you are working with `feature` and `test` branches I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed.

Even if you do this some time later and remove someone else's commit from `test`, you can simply merge those back in again after you are done.

If it was a just single commit, `git revert` would be fine although it creates a new commit but for merge commits, getting rid of it is definitely simpler, more effective and less error-prone than reverting.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the missing commits are not too many.
Then below 2 command will do some help.

1)on the branch the missed commit formerly exist,

`$ git reflog | grep -i "key-word-of-the-commit"`

get the `commit-id-missed` from above

It is better to check the commit content before going to 2）

`$ git show commit-id-missed`

2)on the destination branch where you want to merge this commit,

`$ git cherry-pick commit-id-missed`

It will recover all the fault process you made. But if there are too many commits,it will be a time wasting disaster.